Let $G$ be a cyclic group with $|G| = n$. Show that if $m$ is a positive integer, then there exists an element of order $m\in G$ iff $m|n$.
Let $G$ be a cyclic group with $|G| = n$. Show that if $m$ is a positive integer, then there exists an element of order $m\in G$ iff $m|n$.
This is an exercise from Saracino's Abstract Algebra. I am looking for verification and a bit of help with my trouble step.
First, assume that $m|n$, so $\exists q \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $mq=n$. We need $h\in G$ where $h^m=e$.
Since $G$ is cyclic, and $m|n$, there exists $H < G$ where $|H| = m$ (by a previous result I've shown). Further, since $G$ is cyclic all its subgroups are too (by another previous result), so $H$ is cyclic and generated by some $h\in H$ of order $m$. $h\in G$ as well, so we're done.
I think that direction is pretty good, but I'm stuck on one part of the forward direction:
Let $|G| = n$ and let $h\in G$ with order $m$. Show that $m|n$. By the division algorithm we have $n = mq+r$ where $0 \leq r < m$. If we can show that $r = 0$, we are done.
We have $ h^n = h^{mq+r} = (h^m)^qh^r = h^r $ so we know that $h^n = h^r$.
How can I conclude that $r = 0$? Am I missing something obvious? Could I just use Lagrange to immediately jump to the forward conclusion instead?

Notice that $h^n=e$.

@ArturoMagidin If $h^n = e$, then $h^r = e$, but the order of $h$ is $m$, the smallest positive integer that makes $h^x = e$, so $r$ must be 0?
How can we know for sure that $h^n = e$? That means it would generate $G$?

Lagrange tells you $h^n=e$.

Duplicate ....

For the first direction, it's easier to let $g$ be the element generating $G$. So,
$$
G = \{e = g^0, g, \dots, g^{n-1}\}.
$$
If $m\mid n$ then $mq = n$ for some $q$ and $g^q$ is an element of order $m$.
Conversely, suppose $n = mq + r$ with $r\in \{0, \dots, m-1\}$. Then, as you wrote, if $h$ is an element of order $m$ then $h^n = h^r$. Since $h^n = e$, we have $h^r = e$ so the order of $h$ is at most $r<m$.
Note that $h^n = e$ can be seen by writing $h = g^k$ for some integer $k$. Then $h^n = g^{kn} = (g^n)^k = e^k = e$.
